# Checking user touched in a closed area

Tags: algorithm, opengl, graphics

I have a 3D world with curves. Each curve is simply a list of 3D points.
When user clicks on the scree, i would like to test if the point is in a closed area. 
For example, the user draws four curves that form a rectangle. If he clicks inside this rectangle i would like to "know" that it is a closed area.

I could not find any known algorithms - how i can achieve this behaviour?

Comment: You have some weird-formed lines (without area/content) and want to check if a point is "close" to it. Correct? Then define close. Distance to the nearest curve point <=xyz or something else?

Comment: OK, i probably was not clear enough. This is not what i want - i will edit my question

Comment: Since a rectangle is 2D: A) All is 2D, no 3D included. B) The rectangle stands somewhere in a 3D room and a point is only "in" it if it is exactly between the lines, ie. if there would be a plane filling that rectangle, the point is only in it if it touches this plane or C) The point is also in it if it don´t touch that plane. Like, the rectangle´s plane is a light source in normal direction and the point is in closed area if it is in the light ray. In this case, what to do with not planar-areas inide the forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "closed areas" are all planar: For each area, find the point of intersection between the pick-ray and the area's plane. Then use an odd-even crossing test (following a ray in that plane) to determine whether the point is inside that area.

If your areas are not planar, you can instead use a winding test, where you sum the signed angles about the pick-ray of each consecutive pair of points in the area, and see whether that sum is nonzero (accounting for numerical drift).

Comment: This will tell me if a point is inside a given area. However, all i have is curves - i don't know that the area is closed. This is actually what i want to test.

Comment: It sounds like all you have is "points". What distinguishes points forming a closed area, from points forming an open area? Doesn't any list of points define a (possibly nonplanar) polygon?

Comment: A polygon yes, but not necessarily a closed polygon.

Comment: A polygon is closed by definition. Any sequence of 3 or more points defines a closed polygon. Just draw a line segment between each two consecutive points, and from the last point to the first point.

Comment: You are correct :) I meant that it can just be a 3D polyline. Not closed